# Enabling drag-and-drop file transfer between host and guests in KVM_QEMU on Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, virtual-machine, kvm, qemu

I am running Windows 7-10 guests on an Arch Linux host, and I have tried using Virtualbox, Vmware, and KVM_QEMU.

I have found that the best performance is with KVM_QEMU, but I am unable to drag and drop files between the guest and host.

I have searched for solutions online but have only found outdated ones that do not work on my machine. Can you offer any advice?

I already installed the latest spice-guest:
I can drag and drop only from host to guest and not form guest to host, also copy/cut and past not work between host and guest.
I know that I can do a shared folder but I would avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install a suitable guest integration on your virtual machine. For Windows guests on KVM_QEMU you can find them [here](https://www.spice-space.org/download.html).

Each hypervisor has its own set of tools to handle this integration

- For KVM_QEMU, you can use [SPICE Guest Tools](https://www.spice-space.org/download.html)
- For VMware, use [VMware tools](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1014294), or optionally open-vm-tools on Linux
- For VirtualBox they're called [Guest Additions](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html)

The latest version of SPICE Guest Tools for Windows can be downloaded directly from here: https://www.spice-space.org/download/windows/spice-guest-tools/spice-guest-tools-latest.exe